# Analog input matrix (chessbooard)

Tags: hardware, sensor

I cannot find anything related to this problem anywhere, does it mean it's impossible?
I want to have a chessboard with piece type recognition.
My idea is to plug pieces into the chessboard using some connector, which is connected to a resistor inside the piece, different in each piece type.
I would like to use single 8-channel ADC, which would connect to rows, and then scan one square at a time by switching one column on and others off.
I would have to use pull-down or pull-up resistors for unoccupied squares, and probably diodes to prevent current from flowing back to gpios, therefore changing the value read.
My question is, is this even possible?
Will the read speed be high enough to suit the purpose?
Will it work as good as using 64 analog inputs?

Please include diagram if wiring improvement is needed.

I'm not a native english speaker and write on mobile keyboard, so I am sorry for mistakes :/

Comment: A question very similar to this was asked on the Arduino forum a few years back. It's worth you trying to find the thread as there were several ideas put forward.

Comment: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=chess%20is%3aquestion ?

Comment: @starfish I have already seen these answers, but this still seems best to me (if it will work)

Comment: [This one](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=190291.0) I think it was.

Comment: It's quite workable, although the plugging may be an expensive hassle. Consider audio jack type plugs? Apply power to rows, read columns.